# facebook share button with multimedia video tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have a html page to share a html 5 video and I want to create a share button.

So far I have this one...

```
 <a name="fb_share" share_url = " @Url.Action("Details", "Player", new { area = "Multimedia", id = item.Id }, "http")" ></a>
```

...that generates the url `http://host/Multimedia/Composer/Player/Details/{Id}`
and it works like you can see in this picture.

[image]

And I was using this facebook library:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"  
    type="text/javascript">
```

I was wondering what's the easy way to show the page or a preview of the video?

The same link with a YouTube anchor shows something like this:

[image]

I got it from this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

And I saw there's some metatags but for `.fla` or `.swf` videos and mine is html5. I wonder if there's a similar way to pass the metadata to show it like the second link.